# ASP.NET Entity Framework, Add Table to Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx

So I've found similar questions, but could really use some help! I have an Entity Framework Application with a whole bunch of tables. I've had to add a new table, and I understand that I can get the model to update using the wizard from .edmx file. The problem is that I REALLY don't want to udpate all of the other models. I've added validation for my models as they're being used in forms, regenerating these models will get rid of all that code. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to preserve the changes you made to the auto-generated classes as part of the .edmx.

This may not be the answer you want to hear, but your situation is one of many reasons to use different classes for your user submitted data (i.e. web form in your case).

A few other reasons you should separate your models:

- Prevent over-posting which could result in bad data or even security issues
- Keep your data models clean and simple by avoiding having UI specific properties (e.g. `SelectList` which is an object to help populate `<select>` elements, but doesn't need to be part of the database)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Understood though, thanks a lot for the answer! I'm just learning MVC, and that's the way I was taught to do it - clearly gonna have to look more into best practices.